# camera mobile phone takes pictures at constant focal length if 3.5 mm.supposed to have autofocus and touchfocus

Tags: autofocus, focal-length, camera-basics, lens-design, camera-settings

This is a cheap Chinese landvo l200
Android mtk65xx mobile
The onlything it keeps
Changing is IS0 from 150 to 800 +
And exposure time
I wondered how can it autofocus and touch
Focus when it keeps focal length constant
@ 3.5mm.
Is that the case with all phones ?
Or maybe some high end ones like xperia
And HTC have something more in the camera lens

Answer (score 0):

> how can it autofocus and touch Focus when it keeps focal length constant @ 3.5mm.

Because focussing is not about changing the focal length. Changing the focal length is called zooming, which your phone-cam doesn't do. Not optically anyway.

Focussing involves changing the distance between (parts of) the lens and the sensor.